# neo4j: How to count number of elements in a list?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to count the number of elements in a list

```
UNWIND [{id:'0001',name:'Test',size:'10mm'}] as rows
RETURN size(rows)
```

However i get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the rows and as you unwind them there will always be only a single row. Try counting the keys for example:

```
UNWIND [{id:'0001',name:'Test',size:'10mm'}] as rows
RETURN size(keys(rows))
```